# d == 9000000000000000000d infinite loop

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
double d = 9000000000000000000d;
while (d == 9000000000000000000d)
{
   d += 500;
   Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

Why does the code run into an infinite loop?

**Why doesn't the compiler throw any exception?**

Comment: Double can store 15 significant digits.  Adding 500 thus simply cannot change the value.  Something the debugger can easily show you.

Comment: Can you show the output of `Console.WriteLine`? just curios...

Comment: @RenéVogt Console.WriteLine prints 9E+18

Comment: Why would a compiler *ever* throw an exception?

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you had chosen `d += 513;` or anything bigger than that, you wouldn't have realized of this as the loop stops exactly after the first time

Comment: You can also consider using `System.Numerics.BigInteger` if you need greater precision than what `decimal` provides.

Comment: Compilers don't throw exceptions. And it doesn't produce an error because this is a runtime problem. If there should be an exception at runtime would be an interesting discussion. I think there is nothing really exceptional to this situation. Floating point computations have a lot of pitfalls developers should be aware of.

Comment: `Why compiler doesn't thrown exception?` Why should it? That's how floating point numbers work and how those are defined.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A double has a varying precision, i.e. a fixed number of significant bits.

A double/float number (floating point number) consists of an exponent and a mantisse (cf. the [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard). The logic bebind this is that with larger numbers one doesn't need a high precision for small numbers, whereas for small numbers one needs a high precision. So, it might happen that `d==d+1` is true as `+1` does nothing for large numbers (That's also a reason why one [should not use floating point numbers for representing money](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/3906760); also comparing floating point numbers is problematic as `4*0.1!=0.4` might be true, depending on the implementation and possible rounding errors). This is defined in the [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard and, thus, won't throw any exception (btw. compilers can issue warning or errors, but don't throw any exceptions).

That's in contrast to integers which always have a precision of `1`. So, if you need to handle large numbers with a precision of 1, you need to consider to use [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) implementations or use [`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/364x0z75.aspx) with a fixed set of decimal digits and guaranteed precision.